# Recursive data structures in haskell: prolog-like terms

Tags: haskell, grammar, bnf, recursive-datastructures

I have a question about recursive data structures in Haskell (language that  I'm currently trying to learn).

I would like to encode in Haskell Prolog-like terms, but every solution I came up with has different drawbacks that I would really like to avoid. I would like to find a cheap and elegant way of encoding a BNF grammar in Haskell types, if you wish to see my problem from this perspective.

Just as a reminder, some prolog terms could be `male`, `sum(2, 3.1, 5.1)`, `btree(btree(0, 1), Variable)`.

#### Solution 1

```
data Term = SConst String
          | IConst Integer
          | FConst Double
          | Var    String
          | Predicate   {predName :: String, predArgs :: [Term]}
```

With this solution I can have nested predicates (since `predArgs` are `Term`), but I can't distinguish predicates from other terms in type signatures.

#### Solution 2

```
data Term = SConst String
          | IConst Integer
          | FConst Double
          | Var    String

data Predicate = Predicate {predName :: String, predArgs ::[Either Term Predicate}
```

In this variant I can clearly distinguish predicates from basic terms, but the `Either` type in the `predArgs` list can be quite a nuisance to manage later in the code (I think... I'm new to Haskell).

#### Solution 3

```
data Term = SConst String
          | IConst Integer
          | FConst Double
          | Var    String
          | Struct String [Term]

data Predicate = Predicate String [Term]
```

With this last solution, I split terms in two different types as before, but this time I avoid `Either Term Predicate` adding a `Struct` constructor in `Term` with basically the same semantics as `Predicate`.

It's just like solution 1 with two predicate constructors for terms. One is recursion-enabled, `Struct`, and the other one, `Predicate` is to be able to distinguish between predicates and regular terms.

The problem with this try is that `Struct` and `Predicate` are structurally equivalent and have almost the same meaning, but I will not be able to write functions that works - in  example - both on `(Predicate "p" [])` and `(Struct "p" [])`.

So again my question is: please, is there a better way to encode my predicates and terms such that:

1. I'm able to distinguish between predicate and terms in type signatures;
2. nested predicates like `p(q(1), r(q(3), q(4)))` are supported;
3. I can write functions that will work uniformly on predicates, without any
   distinction like the one in solution #3?

Please feel free to ask me for further clarifications should you need any.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you want to be able to disinguish predicates and terms from their type signature? Is there any function that works on a predicate but not on a term? I would suggest you to google for "GADT" (generalized algebraic datatypes). They allow you to use method 1 while being able to carry information for the type system.

Comment: Yes, I want to model a simple intelligent Agent and it's beliefs will be encoded as predicates.
I'll have a look at that GADT, thanks.

Comment: GADT is a nice extension to the language, but it seems a little bit an overkill for my needs.

Comment: Do it as you like. GADTs are just an idea how to solve the problem. They are especially great to embedd a type system into Haskell for a DSL. I also think, that the idea of pat is quite good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a term constructor to wrap a predicate.  Here, I also factored all of the literals into their own data type:

```
data Term = TLit    Literal
          | TVar    String
          | TPred   Predicate

data Literal = LitS String
             | LitI Int
             | LitF Double

data Predicate = Predicate String [Term]
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll go on using your solution since it's the simplest one that fulfills my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way (that's probably not worth the trouble):

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}

-- 'T' and 'F' are short for 'True' and 'False'
data T = T
data F

-- 'p' is short for 'mayNotBeAPredicate'
data Term p
    = SConst !p String
    | IConst !p Integer
    | FConst !p Double
    | Var    !p String
    | Predicate {predName :: String, predArgs :: [Term T]}

sconst :: String -> Term T
iconst :: Integer -> Term T
fconst :: Double -> Term T
var :: String -> Term T
predicate :: String -> [Term T] -> Term p
sconst = SConst T
iconst = IConst T
fconst = FConst T
var = Var T
predicate = Predicate

checkPredicate :: Term p -> Maybe (Term F)
checkPredicate (Predicate name args) = Just (Predicate name args)
checkPredicate _ = Nothing

forgetPredicate :: Term p -> Term T
forgetPredicate (SConst _ s) = sconst s
forgetPredicate (IConst _ i) = iconst i
forgetPredicate (FConst _ f) = fconst f
forgetPredicate (Var    _ s) = var s
forgetPredicate (Predicate name args) = predicate name args
```

You can now write functions which only accept predicates by giving them an input type of `Term F`, and functions which accept any input type by giving them an input type of `Term p`.

Comment: Thanks, that's cool! I have to remember this trick, it could be useful at some point. For my current basic needs, as already stated by you, it's a little bit too complicated.